# Can't move starting point of rectangle

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning, coordinates, draw, pattern

I want to draw a rectangle which starts in these coordinates: from northwest(3,0) to southeast(4,-2). Here is the code:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,oneside]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {images/} }
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\usepackage{caption}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\noindent
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.\\

\noindent
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[pattern=north east lines, pattern color=black] (3,0) rectangle ++(1,2);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

But it doesn't work. So I tried adding [shift={(3,0)},...] and [xshift={3},...]. They also didn't work. I can't move a simple rectangle. Here is the picture that I want to draw:
[image: I just want to draw pattern filled rectangle first]

Comment: Since there is no other content in the drawing it doesn't surprise me that `\draw[pattern=north east lines, pattern color=black] (0,0) rectangle ++(1,2);` and `\draw[pattern=north east lines, pattern color=black] (3,0) rectangle ++(1,2);` give the same output. What do you want to achieve? Why do you need to start at `(3,0)` rather than `(0,0)`. What is the expected output (can you add a picture that shows the difference between the current and desired state)?

Comment: Also: Welcome to TeX.SX!

Comment: TikZ shrinks down its final box to the smallest rectangle upon exit no matter what the coordinates are. They are internal coordinates not page coordinates.

Comment: @moewe Thank you very much. Here is the stuff that I want to draw. (http://i64.tinypic.com/2ibjeaf.png) I don't want it to start from beginning of the line(0,0). Now it starts from (0,0) even I typed (3,0).

Comment: @percusse Thank you. That sounds awful because it's not logical. Why is it too hard to locate a simple box?

Comment: The stupid-but-simple solution would bet to put an empty node at `(0,0)`: `\node (0,0) {};` But I'm sure there are better methods...

Comment: For me it would be illogical if the coordinates were relative to the page. The diagram is a separate environment. If you want to tell TeX to move the box that is the `tikzpicture` 3cm right you could add `\hspace*{3cm}` just before it. @moewe's suggestion would almost work, but because of the default inner sep of a node, the left edge of the diagram would actually be at -0.333em of the coordinate system of the `tikzpicture`. On the other hand, something  like `\path (0,0) -- (3,0);` would work I think, or add `inner sep=0` to the node options.

Comment: @Rageful I think you have a different idea of how TikZ works. TeX doesn't understand anything about graphics. It just stacks boxes. TikZ tells to TeX that *I'm a box of <x, y> size and place me on the page when it is my turn*. If you want page coordinates TikZ also has some capabilities but not via shifting coordinates. Can you reword your question about what to draw and where to draw it?

Comment: Does adding `\path (0,0);` give you what you want?

Comment: @percusse Thank you for your valuable explanation. I edited the question and added an image.

Comment: @marmot Yes, it worked. But I don't have any idea how.

Comment: `\path (0,0);` (similar to mine and moewe's suggestions above) adds an invisible path to the `tikzpicture`, and that path is taken into account when the size of the `tikzpicture` is calculated.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as solved in the comments.

Comment: @Bobyandbob Yes.